# Custom field only on custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I have added some fields to a custom post type through

```
function add_electric_portfolio_box() {
        add_meta_box(
                "electric_portfolio_info", __('Detalles de la web'), "electric_portfolio_fields", "electric_portfolio", "normal"
        );    
}
```

Which I then call with:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'add_electric_portfolio_box');
```

But now those custom fields appear in regular pages too. Is it posible to show those fields ONLY on that type of post?

Here is a screenshot of the undesired fields in the regular pages
[image: Undesired fields]

as opposed to the desired fields in the custom post:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just check the post type of the post you're on.

```
global $post; // make sure $post is available
if( get_post_type( $post ) == 'your_custom_post_type's_name' ) {
    add_meta_box( ... );
}
```

UPDATE: I think the $post variable might not have been getting passed to `get_post_type`.

Comment: get_post_type returns false. Maybe it is because of the way I add the meta box? (Check out my edits)

Comment: Try the updated snippet.

Comment: I keep getting false :S By the way... I add the post type on a plugin, maybe that's the reason?